# Undesired output in Javascript While loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I get output of below code as n = 3, x = 6
but I require output as

```
n = 1, x = 1
n = 2, x = 3
n = 3, x = 6
```

Can some one help me what else should be added in code?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    function myFunction() {
        var n = 0;
        var x = 0;
        while (n < 3) {
            n++;
            x += n;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "n = " + n + ", " + "x = " + x;
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

@Jai Below example is similar,

```
function myFunction() {
    var text = "";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        text += "<br>The number is " + i;
        i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

output is

```
The number is 0  
 The number is 1
  ...
```

Comment: If any response help you, you should accept the answer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . ;) I see that another questions that you made, you don't accept any answer, and maybe you are new here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
    var n = 0;
    var x = 0;
    while (n < 3) {
        n++;
        x += n;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += 
    "n = " + n + ", " + "x = " + x;
    }

}
```

You have to "add" to inner html. So, put "+=" and inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the `innerHTML` and put it in loop:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += 
"n = " + n + ", " + "x = " + x;

} // <---end of while
```

Comment: can you help me understand why are we concatenating innerHTML because other examples I went through had document.getElementById outside while loop. 

Can I paste the link to example here?

Comment: @Mihir its because `innerHTML` replaces all the existing contents of that element. But adding new content with existing contents should be done with `+=`.

Comment: I have added another example in my first post but concatenation is not used there. am not able to relate whether both scenarios referred are different?

Comment: That is another way via defining a variable `text` to store the result and when loop exits all the appended values set via innerHTML. and in this case you don't have to put innerHTML inside of loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code executes the while loop 3 times, updating the values of n and x each time. But because you write the output outside of the while loop, you only see the last values. You need to put a line that displays your variables INSIDE the while loop.